# javascript board game piece placement

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a board game in java script, and what i'm trying to accomplish is: layout the board(chess/checkers format) Then add pieces to the board based on position. So for example i want to be able to write code for piece a to be moved onto tile 10.

So far in my code i have a loop to create the board but don't a method to properly name the tiles, so that the piece can correctly be placed on the tile.

```
for (i=0; i<64; i++){
    var tile = cc.Sprite.create(res.myTile_png);
    this.addChild(tile,0);
    x = centerpos.x + ((i % 8) - 3.5) * tile.getBoundingBox().width;
    y = centerpos.y + (Math.floor(i / 8) - 3.5) * tile.getBoundingBox().height;
    tile.setPosition(x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about doing this would be to assign a unique integer identifier to every distinct piece in the game, and then maintain a matrix of dimensions equal to the # of rows x # of columns on the board, with values of the piece identifiers in the correct address in the matrix that would correspond to their position on the board.

For instance, the starting arrangement of pieces in checkers can be represented by:

```
[
  [  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1 ],
  [ -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0 ],
  [  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1 ],
  [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
  [  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0 ],
  [  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1 ],
  [  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0 ]
]
```

with, say, `-1` representing white, and `1` representing red pieces on the board.

The tile elements of the board can also be kept in a matrix, so that the two matrices can be iterated over together to place the pieces in corresponding locations.

The unique ids can also then be used as CSS class names, or image file names to be attached to the element representing the piece.